# Remove all parameters from specific URL

Tags: .htaccess

How do I get this original URL:
https://www.example.com/search-for-commercial-doors.html?format=json&task=suggestions.suggest&tmpl=component

To be rewritten to:
https://www.example.com/search-for-commercial-doors.html

Code that is not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search-for-commercial-doors\.html$ /search-for-commercial-doors.html? format=json&task=suggestions.suggest&tmpl=component [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess Rules file. Make sure your htaccess file is present along with search-for-commercial-doors.html in same folder, also clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond ^(search-for-commercial-doors\.html)/?$ $1?format=json&task=suggestions.suggest&tmpl=component [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: This gets a 500 - Internal Server Error.